# "Fly in" effect with CSS and/or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I was wondering if there is a possibility to make "fly in" effect using CSS and/or some script like in PowerPoint presentation.

So I need object to "fly in" from the left, and object to "fly in" from the right side of the browser.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you have an example of the "fly in" effect ?

Comment: Something like  : http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-Elements-Fly-in-Effects-On-Scroll.html

Comment: Look at this website [Click Here](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). Look through the animations and find the one your looking for.

Comment: @DavidLaberge I believe the times when jQuery served as web animation engine are already gone - since CSS3 transition and animation and javascript web API.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/zxxqy7u8/) and read something about [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

CSS

```
#flyin { font-size: 0; opacity: 0; transition: 1000ms; }
#flyin.run { font-size: 20px; opacity: 1; }
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("flyin").className = "run";
```

HTML

```
<div id="flyin">Fly-in</div>
```